# How many agents JADE handle on contract net protocol

Tags: java, agents-jade

My question is about how many agents that JADE can handle when using contract net protocol?
I have one ContractNetInitiator agent and 130 ContractNetResponder on the same container. the code used to create those agents is as follow:

```
ProfileImpl profileImpl2 = new ProfileImpl(false);
        profileImpl2.setParameter(ProfileImpl.MAIN_HOST, "localhost");
        AgentContainer agentContainer = runtime.createAgentContainer(profileImpl2);
        
         AgentController v;
         
         for (int i=0; i<130; i++){ //8 est le nombre d'agents véhicules
              v=agentContainer.createNewAgent("vehicle"+i, "VehicleAgent", new Object[]{});
            v.start(); }
```

AND

```
try {
        // Register the vehicle-transporting service in the yellow pages
        dfd = new DFAgentDescription();
        dfd.setName(getAID());
        ServiceDescription sd = new ServiceDescription();
        sd.setName("Transport Of Items");
        sd.setType("Transport");
        dfd.addServices(sd);
        DFService.register(this, dfd);
    } catch (FIPAException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The ContractNetInitiator found only 100 agent.the code I used to search these agents is as follow:

```
try {
        // search list of Vehicle agents
        template = new DFAgentDescription();
        sd = new ServiceDescription();
        sd.setType("Transport");
        template.addServices(sd);

        DFAgentDescription[] result = DFService.search(this, template);

        if (result.length > 0) {
            vehicleAgentsD = new AID[result.length];
            log.info("Agent Dispatcher Agent  found  this vehicle's Agents :");
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
                vehicleAgentsD[i] = result[i].getName();
                log.info("VA" + i + "===>" + vehicleAgentsD[i].getName());
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Agent " + getLocalName() + " did not find any service");
        }

    } catch (FIPAException fe) {
        fe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is this error related to the limitation of JADE or to my computer performance?
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Could you please format your code with the "{}" so that we can see what of this text exactly is your code

Comment: no, you have to edit your question and than add your code

Comment: @Verity I edited my question

Comment: now you have to format it correctly ;) And than your question is okay and we can answer you :D

Answer (score 1):

The `DFService` seems to have a default limit on the number of results it returns set to 100. You can **lower** it by setting appropriate `SearchConstraints` for the `DFService.search()` method like this

```
SearchConstraints getAll = new SearchConstraints();
getAll.setMaxResults(new Long(max_results));
DFAgentDescription dfd = new DFAgentDescription();
ServiceDescription sd  = new ServiceDescription();
sd.setType( "service-proxy" );
dfd.addServices(sd);
DFAgentDescription[] result = DFService.search(this, dfd,getAll);
```

In order to **increase** this value, you need to set the property `jade_domain_df_maxresult` to a higher value and provide it to the container at creation time:

```
Profile pMain = new ProfileImpl(null, 8888, null);
pMain.setParameter("jade_domain_df_maxresult", "1000");
AgentContainer mc = rt.createMainContainer(pMain);
```

This answer is based on [these](https://jade.tilab.com/pipermail/jade-develop/2012q3/018532.html) [answers](https://jade.tilab.com/pipermail/jade-develop/2012q3/018536.html) in jade-develop mailing list.

Thanks to Farida for mentioning the problem with my original answer and for pointing to the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you for your intervention professor @Martin Pilat. I tried the solution proposed but this does not work for me. However, following the link you shared (https://jade.tilab.com/pipermail/jade-develop/2012q3/018536.html),  the answer given works. I add this lines to my code: `Profile pMain = new ProfileImpl(null, 8888, null);
             pMain.setParameter("jade_domain_df_maxresult", "1000");
             AgentContainer mc = rt.createMainContainer(pMain);`